# XPATH getting children of a specific node

Tags: xpath

i have this xml, and i dont know how to get the names of the children given a name also.

```
    <return_message>
    <status>True</status>
        <return_value>
        <folder_tree_node>
  <folder>
    <name>CR1</name>
    <path>Root\Test Sets\WBTS SW CI\CR1</path>
  </folder>
  <folder_tree_node>
    <folder>
      <name>FB14.07</name>
      <path>Root\Test Sets\WBTS SW CI\CR1\FB14.07</path>
    </folder>
    <folder_tree_node>
      <folder>
        <name>CW27_1</name>
        <path>Root\Test Sets\WBTS SW
        CI\CR1\FB14.07\CW27_1</path>
      </folder>
      <folder_tree_node>
        <folder>
          <name>Antenna Line Mng</name>
          <path>Root\Test Sets\WBTS SW
          CI\CR1\FB14.07\CW27_1\ Line Mng</path>
        </folder>
      </folder_tree_node>
      <folder_tree_node>
        <folder>
          <name>BTS start up &amp; Rec</name>Antenna
          <path>Root\Test Sets\WBTS SW
          CI\CR1\FB14.07\CW27_1\BTS start up &amp; Rec</path>
        </folder>
      </folder_tree_node>
      <folder_tree_node>
        <folder>
          <name>CC &amp; SM</name>
          <path>Root\Test Sets\WBTS SW CI\CR1\FB14.07\CW27_1\CC
          &amp; SM</path>
        </folder>
      </folder_tree_node>
      <folder_tree_node>
        <folder>
          <name>Frequency Variants</name>
          <path>Root\Test Sets\WBTS SW
          CI\CR1\FB14.07\CW27_1\Frequency Variants</path>
        </folder>
      </folder_tree_node>
      <folder_tree_node>
        <folder>
          <name>NetAct Interoperability</name>
          <path>Root\Test Sets\WBTS SW
          CI\CR1\FB14.07\CW27_1\NetAct Interoperability</path>
        </folder>
      </folder_tree_node>
      <folder_tree_node>
        <folder>
          <name>Pre-Stability</name>
          <path>Root\Test Sets\WBTS SW
          CI\CR1\FB14.07\CW27_1\Pre-Stability</path>
        </folder>
      </folder_tree_node>w
      <folder_tree_node>
        <folder>
          <name>RAB</name>
          <path>Root\Test Sets\WBTS SW
          CI\CR1\FB14.07\CW27_1\RAB</path>
        </folder>
      </folder_tree_node>
      <folder_tree_node>
        <folder>
          <name>Test &amp; Measurements</name>
          <path>Root\Test Sets\WBTS SW
          CI\CR1\FB14.07\CW27_1\Test &amp; Measurements</path>
        </folder>
      </folder_tree_node>
      <folder_tree_node>
        <folder>
          <name>Tracebility</name>
          <path>Root\Test Sets\WBTS SW
          CI\CR1\FB14.07\CW27_1\Tracebility</path>
        </folder>
      </folder_tree_node>
      <folder_tree_node>
        <folder>
          <name>Transmission</name>
          <path>Root\Test Sets\WBTS SW
          CI\CR1\FB14.07\CW27_1\Transmission</path>
        </folder>
      </folder_tree_node>
    </folder_tree_node>
```

I want to get all the names of the children of a given node. I.E given CW27_1, xpath would return the ff. Antenna Line Mng, BTS startup, CC& amp . What xpath should i have to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
//folder_tree_node/folder/name[.='CW27_1']/../../folder_tree_node/descendant::name
```

it will get the following:

```
<name>Antenna Line Mng</name>
<name>BTS start up &amp; Rec</name>
<name>CC &amp; SM</name>
<name>Frequency Variants</name>
<name>NetAct Interoperability</name>
<name>Pre-Stability</name>
<name>RAB</name>
<name>Test &amp; Measurements</name>
<name>Tracebility</name>
<name>Transmission</name>
```